# PHP: str_replace does not work for certain characters

Tags: php, str-replace, ampersand

I have the following code to replace certain characters:

```
<?php
function xmlEscape($string)
{
    return str_replace(array('&', '<', '>', '\'', '"'), array('&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&apos;', '&quot;'), $string);
}
$xxx = 'The character & is ampersand and < stands for "less than". ';

echo xmlEscape($xxx)." <p/>";
echo str_replace ('&', '&amp;', $xxx."<p/>");
echo str_replace ( 'character','letter', $xxx);
?>
```

The result is :

```
The character & is ampersand and < stands for "less than".
The character & is ampersand and < stands for "less than".
The letter & is ampersand and < stands for "less than".
```

Only the third works fine. What could be the cause ? I once used that code in other scripts and that function worked. What makes a function works in one script and does not work in others ? Using Firefox as browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you trying like this

```
echo str_replace ('&', 'amp', $xxx."<p/>");
```

then it is working fine.

`"&amp;"` is unicode character and it is rendering on browser if you want to see the changes check it on firebug.

Comment: Pretty much any character is "unicode character", that's the idea behind Unicode. That said, the ampersamp is even an ASCII character. I think this is called "HTML character reference".

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it works properly. If you see your browser source code, you will see

```
The character &amp; is ampersand and &lt; stands for "less than".  <p>
The character &amp; is ampersand and &lt; stands for "less than". </p>
<p>The letter &amp; is ampersand and &lt; stands for "less than".
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... Looks like it is replaced! But the browser interprets the escape character and displays it again as "&".